# Java Serialization with YAML (SnakeYaml Library), HashMaps are not shown in serialized output

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, yaml, snakeyaml

when i serialize a class object such that:

```
class MyClass{

   String value;
   public MyClass(){}

   public void setValue(String value){
      this.value = value;
   }

   public String getValue(){
      return value;
   }

}
```

and serializing it like:

```
 MyClass c1 = new MyClass();
    c1.setValue("this is a value");
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    result.put("MyClass", c1);
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    String output = yaml.dump(result);
```

works just fine. However, now if in my class i have another value such that:

```
class MyClass{

   String value;
   Map<Integer, AnotherClass> MyList
   public MyClass(){}

   public void setValue(String value){
      this.value = value;
   }

   Map<Integer, AnotherClass> CList = new HashMap<Integer, AnotherClass>();
   public void setList(AnotherClass AL){
      CList.put(1,AL);
      this.MyList = CList;
   }

   public String getValue(){
      return value;
   }

}
```

and now i repeat the same, the program works but in serialized output, i do not see this HashMap. What is the problem, is there some different approach used to serialize HashMap type objects??  Please suggest....

Comment: Please try to be [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It will help you get answer quicker.

Comment: @edwardw I can not shorten it further, otherwise no one would understand what i am trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no getter for the map, that is why it is ignored.

Comment: i have not shown in the code but i have both getter and setter for the Map Object as well. But it is just simply ignored, i don't know why?

Comment: actually now i tested with other custom object types like getter and setter for simple AnotherClass object, but the result is same. May be YAML does not take into account Objects i guess?

Comment: The most effective way to get the answer is to write a failing JUnit test and create an issue in SnakeYAML: http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/issues/list